# Particle hair and mixamo

Tags: modeling

I created a character and added hair using particle systems. Then I exported it and tried to import it again, but the particle hair disappear.

[image]

[image]

After I converted the hair and bread to mesh and exported it again using both .obj & .fbx, I get the same result (hair and bread disappeared). How to fix this issue?

Comment: FBX and OBJ files don't support Blender's particle system. The only way to export is to convert the particles to objects in the Particle System modifier by clicking Make Instances Real but this could well crash your machine or take a very long time if there are lots of particles as with hair and beards. [This](https://youtu.be/DgISM92UmLQ?t=37) is a quick tutorial just using clumps of grass.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I am having the same issue.